# Woocommerce automatic product update via XML

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a front end developer who builds wordpress themes. I am looking to build an online store within wordpress/woocommerce which contains products from a 3rd party company. However their pricing changes on a daily basis (almost like a flash sale type pricing model) so a product might retail at X amount and then for a few hours drop 60%.

The products and pricing will be supplied within an XML feed. Which is fine, but my concern is that this XML will often be updated and the will need to be automatically replicated across the website, without the need to upload the file to wordpress each time.

Does anyone know if this is even possible with Woocommerce, if so, could you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here the WP Cron job code which will help you initiate automatically after hourly daily or monthly.

```
      add_action( 'wp', 'update_hourly_post_type_update_info');
      function update_hourly_post_type_update_info() {
          // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
          if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'wp_product_variation_hourly' ) ) {
              // Schedule the event
              wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'wp_product_variation_hourly' );
          }
      }

      //Here you need to add the function of XML which replace the price
      function wp_product_variation_hourly(){
          //Your Price updating Code here.
      }
```

I have used this code in project it works fine.